# What is the importance of breaker in underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html), there is code like this:

```
if (iterator.call(context, obj[keys[i]], keys[i], obj) === breaker) return;
```

for example in "each" function

```js
var each = _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
  if (obj == null) return;
  if (nativeForEach && obj.forEach === nativeForEach) {
    obj.forEach(iterator, context);
  } else if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
    for (var i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
      if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
    }
  } else {
    var keys = _.keys(obj);
    for (var i = 0, length = keys.length; i < length; i++) {
      if (iterator.call(context, obj[keys[i]], keys[i], obj) === breaker) return;
    }
  }
};
```

I don't understand, why add this `if(xxx === breaker) return;`? When will `iterator.call(context, obj[keys[i]], keys[i], obj) === breaker`?

Comment: @lucuma, seems so, thanks for your link :)

Comment: @lucuma, thanks again, from the link you provided, I found the answer I am looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Annotated source code](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-5),

```
Establish the object that gets returned to break out of a loop iteration.
```

It is just a sentinel value and if the iterator function returns `breaker`, `_.each` will return immediately. Since, `breaker` is not assigned to any other object, no other object can be equal to `breaker` (it is matched with `===`). It is used internally, by [`_.every`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-20) and [`_.any`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-21).

`_.every`

```
if (!(result = result && iterator.call(context, value, index, list))) return breaker;
```

`_.any`

```
if (result || (result = iterator.call(context, value, index, list))) return breaker;
```

These two functions return `breaker`, so that `_.each` will break out of the iterations.

Answer (score 1):

It is used in other `_underscore` helpers, like `_.all()`, `_.every()`, `_.any()` which use the `_.each()` function to loop through the collection, but return the `breaker` when they wanna stop the each loop (i.e. they found the element they were looking for etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll up in the code, you will see the following code:

```
var breaker = {};
```

So it is checking if the function it is calling (the `iterator`) is returning an empty object. If it is, the each "loop" is broken and the function ends.