# Why does underscore use object as breaker

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I just started reading the `underscore annotated source code`,I found that they use the `Object literal {}` as a `breaker` like this:

```
else if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
  for (var i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
  }
} 
else {
  var keys = _.keys(obj);
  for (var i = 0, length = keys.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (iterator.call(context, obj[keys[i]], keys[i], obj) === breaker) return;
}
```

And is `+` used in the if statement for converting from `string` to `number` and for string concatenation in addition to it's regular arithmetic use.

I have tried:

```
console.log(+"5");//=>5
console.log(+5);//=>5
console.log(5===+5);//=>true
```

Comment: @thefourtheye why use `===+` for comparision?

Comment: Please check the [ECMA 5.1 Standard Specification for Unary + operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.6). It explicitly converts the expression to a number.

Comment: Also check my answer for the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21234532/1903116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`===` will return `true` only if the objects are the same. Check this out

```
console.log({} === {});
# false
```

`underscore.js` uses this fact. `breaker` is actually a sentinel value. Lets take the function you have quoted in the question, `_.each`. The second parameter (`iterator`), is a function. If you look at the `_.all` and `_.any` functions, they do something like this

**_.all**

```
each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
  if (!(result = result && predicate.call(context, value, index, list))) return breaker;
});
```

**_.any**

```
each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
  if (result || (result = predicate.call(context, value, index, list))) return breaker;
});
```

They both make use of the `each` function, which is where the check you mentioned in the question happens. If the `predicate` function passed to `_.all` or `_.any` returns a falsy value, we should immediately break out of the iteration. This is called short circuiting. But, ideally  `each` cannot be short-circuited. To overcome that, they use that `breaker` object. When the `iterator` function of `each` returns a `breaker`, `each` will know that, the call is made internally (as only the `breaker` object can be equal to the `breaker` object, see the first code sample in this answer) so it has to break immediately.

That is why `breaker` is used.

Regarding the second part of your question, the unary `+` operator has been designed to convert the expression to a number. Quoting from the [ECMA 5.1 Specification for the Unary + operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.6),

```
1. Let expr be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
2. Return ToNumber(GetValue(expr)).
```